# Using Google Prediction API outside Google App Engine?

Tags: api, google-app-engine, rest, google-prediction

I tried to search for algorithms about predicting future trends and I found Google Prediction API a good fit for me. I wanted to use it in my project but I can't find any useful information about their RESTful API and their examples are for Google App Engine only.

Can the Google Prediction API be used outside App Engine so that I can use it in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear what resources you're looking at, but https://developers.google.com/prediction/ has details about the prediction service in general, and https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/reference/v1.5/ has the more specific api details you're seeking.

The prediction API does not require the use of app engine.